# C WebServer and Python Client

Tags: python, c, sockets, network-programming, client-server

I made a simple webserver using c. I can connect to it via a web browser and it works fine.

The goal of this webserver was to exploit it. So I wrote a simple python script that sends malicious data to the server. However, I only get an error message on the server saying: "Bad file descriptor".

C-Server Main:

```
int main(void) {
  int sockfd, new_sockfd, yes=1; 
  struct sockaddr_in host_addr, client_addr;  
  socklen_t sin_size;

  printf("Accepting web requests on port %d\n", PORT);

  if ((sockfd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
    error_and_exit("in socket");

  if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(int)) == -1)
    error_and_exit("setting socket option SO_REUSEADDR");

  host_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;      
  host_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);    
  host_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; 
  memset(&(host_addr.sin_zero), '\0', 8);

  if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&host_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr))     == -1)
    error_and_exit("binding to socket");

  if (listen(sockfd, 20) == -1)
    error_and_exit("listening on socket");

  while(1) {   // Accept loop
    sin_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    new_sockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &sin_size);
    if(new_sockfd == -1)
      error_and_exit("accepting connection");

    handle_connection(new_sockfd, &client_addr);
  }
 return 0;
}
```

python code:

```
import socket
import struct
import sys
import time

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_address = ('127.0.0.1', 8000)
sock.connect(server_address)

shellcode =(....)

values = ....

try: 
    sock.sendall(values)
finally:
    sock.close()
```

Notes:

1.
the `accept` function (from `<sys/socket.h>`) in the `while(1)` loop returns -1, calling `error_and_exit("accepting connection")`. So the Server never executes `handle_connection` for my python client.

2.
Code for `error_and_exit` function:

```
void error_and_exit(char *message) {
  char error_message[100];

  strcpy(error_message, " Error ");
  strncat(error_message, message, 83);
  perror(error_message);
  exit(-1);
}
```

Comment: `[...] i wrote a simple python script that sends malicious data to the server [...]`: If you don't own that server you might want to think twice before doing that.

Comment: *Where* in the server do you get the error?

Comment: Since you claim that the server "works fine" when you connect to it with a browser but behaves differently when you connect to it with your exploit script, it seems reasonable to think that the details of the client's communication and the server's code for handling it would be central to the problem, yet you do not provide these.  If you want help with code, we ordinarily expect to see a [mcve] representative of the problem.

Comment: sorry guys, i forgot to mention two things, i updated the post.

Comment: Once I added headers, removed the call to `handle_connection`, added `#define PORT 8000`, removed the `shellcode` variable, and hardcoded `values` as a string, the code you posted works fine for me. What is the rest of your code doing?